# What does expanded ISO mean?

Tags: iso, sensor, digital-iso

Especially with regards to image quality.

I am particularly interested in when you expand to a lower ISO, say 50 rather than 100. Generally the standard high ISO is too noisy, with the expanded ISO even more so.